# How to debug npm Electron app in VS Code that's launched with `npm run dev`?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

App launches without any problems when in command line I type: `npm run dev`.

Now I am trying to create launch configuration in Visual Studio Code so I can debug the application. So far I have:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch via NPM",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "dev"
    ],
    "port": 9229,
    "protocol": "legacy"
}
```

Application does quickly start, but than closes. This seems to be related to my Node.js version (v8.9.1). I get error:

```
Cannot connect to runtime; make sure that runtime is in 'legacy' debug mode.
```

I tried using `"protocol": "inspector"` but in that case application doesn't even start, I get error:

```
Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229).
```

I would be really thankful for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug from "toggle developer tool" for child process.

But for main process, I use this:

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "windows": {
         "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
     },
      "args" : ["."]
    }
 ]
}
```